# Matrix represents a bounded linear operator $T \in L (l^ 2 )$ with respect to the orthonormal canonical basis

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the following Jacobi matrix:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots\\
c_2 & a_2 & b_2 & 0 & 0 & \ldots\\
0 & c_3 & a_3 & b_3 & 0 & \ldots\\
0 & 0 & c_4 & a_3 & b_4 & \ldots\\
. & . & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & . & . & . & . \\
. & . & . & . & . & .
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Prove that if

$\beta=\sup\left\lbrace|c_n| + |a_n| + |b_n| : n = 1, 2, \ldots\right\rbrace <\infty$ and

$\alpha = \sup\left\lbrace|b_{n−1}|+|a_n|+|c_{n+1}| : n = 2, 3,\ldots\right\rbrace <\infty$

then the matrix represents a bounded linear operator $T\in L(l^2)$ with respect to the orthonormal canonical basis and that $||T|| ≤ (\alpha\beta)^{1/2}$.

Under what conditions is T compact?

Generalize the result for band matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as Schur's test.

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be any sequences in $\ell^2$.

Then (interpreting the first row appropriately) \begin{align}|\langle (x_n),T(y_n)\rangle|&=|\sum_n\bar{x}_n(c_ny_{n-1}+a_ny_n+b_ny_{n+1})|\\
&\le\sum_{n,m}|x_n|(|c_n|\delta_{m,n-1}+|a_n|\delta_{m,n}+|b_n|\delta_{m,n+1})|y_m|\\
&=\sum_{n,mm}|x_n|d_{m,n}|y_m|\quad\textrm{where}\ d_{m,n}=|c_n|\delta_{m,n-1}+|a_n|\delta_{m,n}+|b_n|\delta_{m,n+1}\\
&\le\sqrt{\sum_{n,m}|x_n|^2d_{m,n}}\sqrt{\sum_{n,m}|y_m|^2d_{m,n}}\quad \textrm{(Cauchy-Schwarz)}\\
&=\sqrt{\sum_n|x_n|^2(|c_n|+|a_n|+|b_n|)}\sqrt{\sum_m(|c_{m+1}|+|a_m|+|b_{m-1}|)|y_m|^2}\\
&\le\sqrt{\alpha\beta}\|(x_n)\|\|(y_m)\|
\end{align}

Hence $\|T\|=\sup_{x,y\ne0}\frac{|\langle x,Ty\rangle|}{\|x\|\|y\|}\le\sqrt{\alpha\beta}$.

The result is easily generalized to banded matrices.